# prove that for every parallelogram

Tags: trigonometry

Prove that for every parallelogram $$d_1^2+d_2^2=2(a^2+b^2)$$
My attempt is:

$d_1^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos\alpha$

$d_2^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(180-\alpha)=a^2+b^2+2ab\cos\alpha$

It follows that: 
$$d_1^2+d_2^2=2(a^2+b^2)$$

but I don't know whether that is correct. Please help me.

Comment: That's a fine solution.  Was that your question?

Comment: why the second angle is $180-\alpha$, or becouse the sum of tha angle in the base of paralelogram is 180

Comment: The adjacent internal angles in a parallelogram are supplementary.  They are same-side interior angles if you consider their common side as a transversal cutting their opposite sides, which are parallel.

Comment: thanky very much sir